# how to make a new page load by sliding over current page

Tags: jquery, pagination

I like the way this site shows you details of a certain project
http://www.craigandkarl.com/#! Go to their work section and click on a thumbnail.  I'd like to duplicate this effect.  I tried to grab all of the code and files related to this website but my page breaks when I try to see the details of a certain project.

I may have to use [enter link description here](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/) to do what I need to get done but that is NOT what craig and karl use for their portfolio.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to accomplish this effect is to have a single div fly out to the left.
This [can be accomplished easily with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works).

Then, you can specify the content you want to load via ajax into this div depending on the thumbnail you press. Again, [jQuery can do this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Here's an example you can surely extend to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/HVFhE/

However, you can see what this site is using just by inspecting its resources like this:

[image]

For example, in their `common.js`

```
.animate({top: $(window).height() + 'px'}, 0)
.load('pages/project.cfm?projectid=' + $.address.parameter('projectid') + '&image=1&top=1', function() {
$('#project-2-footer').stop()
```

Disclaimer: I do not advocate stealing others' code.

Comment: How would I change that code above to load regular web HTML pages?

Comment: What do you mean "regular web html pages"? (As opposed to?) With AJAX, you can call the HTML content of a page and insert it into a slide out div. Based on the example, it sounds like that's what you want to do.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want to just get this done quickly without learning a bunch of new stuff. And that's totally cool, but you may want to at least read up on the $.ajax function and try out some jquery slide effects. It's easier than it looks. And probably a lot easier than transplanting the code on this guy's site.

Comment: in that code above I see .load('pages/project.cfm?projectid='

Comment: Here's a basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/HVFhE/ I'm getting a regular web html page from http://fiddle.jshell.net/MgVJU/show/light/ and inserting it into a div on the current page. If I wanted to, I could make several of these buttons and have them each load a separate page.

Comment: I would rather something where on the main page I could link to a specific page like project1.html  - if you check out their first link it's a href="http://www.craigandkarl.com#!/?projectid=264&amp;image=1"

Comment: Sure thing. Don't forget to vote up and/or select as accepted answers that end up helping you.

Comment: I've just tried to duplicate our jsfiddle -what am I missing here?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready('#clickme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/MgVJU/show/light/',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);
    }  
    });
});

​</script>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body><button id="clickme">Click me</button>

<div id="ajaxDiv">Nothing to see here.</div>​
</body>
</html>

Comment: You're missing jquery. Add this above your javascript: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: I did that - and still nothing happens. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready('#clickme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/MgVJU/show/light/',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);
    }  
    });
});

​</script>

Comment: <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body><button id="clickme">Click me</button>

<div id="ajaxDiv">Nothing to see here.</div>​
</body>
</html>

Comment: And also how would you incorporate the slide effect as http://craigandkarl.com has?

Comment: Before I go on spending time with this, is my answer acceptable? If so, please mark it as such.

Comment: I would start here. Are you familiar with jQuery? http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: yes, I saw that.  I'm just trying to re-create the portfolio section at craigandkarl.com

Comment: I'm lost - I have no idea on how to replicate what craigandkarl.com for their portfolio section

Comment: You'll need to learn how to use jQuery's $.click() method, as well as animation effects like sliding in and out...all in the docs. Then you can define a div which will populate via ajax based on the element you select. SO is mainly for questions about atomic programming issues rather than comprehensive project how-tos so that's the best I can do for now. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, no quick demo for you to show exactly how craigandkarl.com did their portfolio section then???